# How to cutomize TFS build task

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines-build-task

I create custom task for tfs build 2017 that work on windows os, the task logic was written using powershell script and it's work ok.

When I try to implement the same logic for linux using node I have some problems:

1. pickList input type, I can't get value from this input

   `var tl = require('vso-task-lib');
   let project = tl.getInput('project', true);
   echo.arg(project);`

   Is there other way to read value from pickList?
2. multiLine input type, When I print the value I don't see the first line.

   `var tl = require('vso-task-lib'); 
   var json = tl.getInput('json', true); 
   echo.arg(json);`

if you know good Docomantation how to create custom task for TFS 2017/8, 
How to debug custom task (set up environment) it will be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Did you look at the reference tasks? https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first go through [Visual Studio Team Services  Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vsts) if there are some 3rd-party extension meet your requirement. Most of the extensions are open source, you could check and learn their source code.

VSTS and Microsoft also has created a GitHub repo with a number of samples and reading material to get you started, some tutorials for your reference:

- [VSTS Extensions Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples)
- [Develop Extensions for VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/)

About how to debug and test in Linux environment, suggest you take a look at colin's blog: **[Developing a Custom Build vNext Task](https://colinsalmcorner.com/post/developing-a-custom-build-vnext-task-part-2)**

Comment: Thanks, I already looked at the market but I didn't find any good extension. I will check the links you gave me, but I still don't know why the function 'tl.getInput(INPUT, true)' not working as I expected.